# How to get netstat results grouping by app name?

Tags: windows-7, netstat

I use windows 7.  I want get result such as `distinct netstat -b`.

Just get a list of all applications use the network.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PowerShell with the following command:

> netstat -b | select-string ".exe" | sort-object -unique